# Why does German word "deuten" mean "to interpret"?

Tags: etymology

[***deuten***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deuten#Etymology)

> From Middle High German diuten, from Old High German diuten, from Proto-Germanic ***þiudijanan**. 
>   Cognate with Dutch duiden, Icelandic þýða (“translate”), Swedish tyda, Danish tyde. **Related to Deutsch**.

[***Deutsch***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Deutsch)

> the German word for "German;" **see Dutch**.

[***Dutch***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dutch#Etymology)

> From Middle English Duch (“German, Low Countryman”), from Middle Dutch dūtsch, duutsc (modern Duits (“German”)), northern variant of dietsc (compare modern Diets (“Dutch language”)), from Proto-Germanic ***þiudiskaz** (compare German Deutsch (“German”), Old English þēodisc (“of the people”)), from ***þeudō** ‘people’, from Proto-Indo-European ***tewtéh₂**.
>
> See also Derrick, Teuton, Teutonic.
>   Middle Dutch duutsc is the result of i-mutation (umlaut) typical of central dialects (Brabantine) while dietsc shows the merger of iu with io and weakening to [iə] typical of coastal dialects (Flemish). This led to doublets which split in meaning during the Renaissance.

[****tewtéh₂***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Indo-European/tewt%C3%A9h%E2%82%82)

> Noun
>   *tewtéh₂ f
>   **people, tribe**

The reference to "Deutsch" means they are cognates?

If they are, the semantic change from "tribe" to "interpret" seems confusing.

Comment: Reminds me of the word for 'explain' in Hungarian: magyarázat.

Comment: Conversely, the Hungarian for the German language is "németül" -- or, language-of-the-non-speakers[mutes].

Comment: Wikt. on \*þiudijaną says "Origin obscure. Possibly a conflated word, partly from ..."; IMHO, compare *dot*, from a sense "bundle, group, clump" and *point*. *deuten* means also "to point, to point out".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantic extension goes like this: *tribe* -> *explain to the tribe* -> *interpret*. I expect the Hungarian case mentioned by @daf to have an analogous derivation.

Comment: Thank you!!!It is very helpful to know the common phenomena, although the meaning seems a little strange.

Comment: I very much doubt this. The root of *tewtéh₂ is not settled, so it's possible that *deuten* and *deutsch* simply derive from the same root. It's possible that folk etymology, e.g. along your line of reasoning, obscured deeper, perhaps unrelated roots. Given my native intuition about the word *deuten* and its extensions, I'd rather consider \*deyk- "to show, point out", whence *dict-* and *disk* (cp. Norse *tysk* "German") ... Also compare *to tell*, Ger. *Trieb, treiben* (e.g. "to grow", cog. *drive*), *Stamm* "stem, tribe", *zeigen*, *Zeiger*, *Zeichen*.

Comment: Also consider, if Czech *Němec* "German" derives from a sense *unable to speak [Czech]*, then *deutsch* might derive from a sense *able to speak [German]*. *das Volk* "the people", *folgen* "to follow" would also be antithetic to *show, lead*, though that's a false cognate pair, as far as I know. *translate*, *übersetzen* also have a sense of movement, though the latter is probably a calque of the former. It follows that words like *Bedeutung*, *Verstehen*, *understand* and *unterstützen* or *Verhalten*, *Benehmen*, and *Begriff* are terribly difficult, as much as the denoted signs.

Answer (score -1):

In duiden (Dutch) and deuten (German) the native speaker will 'see' in their mind's eye the pointing finger of a person explaining something. In Dutch this is exemplified by the verb *aan*duiden, which implies the indicative gesture even stronger.

Answer (score -3):

Not quite contrary to your sources I would try to relate this to the root of *teach*, Ger. *zeigen*, Lat. *digit* or *dict-*. The set ührase is "Zeichen deuten" and *deuten* is otherwise synonymous with *zeigen*. The semantic derivation--preceding a probably folk etymologic reinterpretation towards "deutsch"--would be *deyḱ-, *show* > *teach* > *teach language* > *interpreter [e.g. of records]* > *explain to the tribe* > ...

Compare *lector*, "someone [able to, in the profession] to read"; *doctor* "?"; *ein Deut*, chiefly used in "keinen Deut besser" (not one bit better), imaginably from "kein' Deut verstehen" ("to understand not one *Deut*"). Looking at *talk*, PIE *del- I come to think, the sequence of derivation may well be different, as a comparison Latin *debeo, habeo* and *lego*, *elect* and *delinquo* may suggest, as the latter relates to PIE *leykʷ- (perfective "to leave") deriving words relating to "remains" and "inheritance" in various languages, and interpretation of cultural heritage through oral tradition and associated cryptic signs is what I'm riffing on.

Speaking of *dict-*, compare *pregnant* "pre+gnoss-", i.e. *showing first signs, foreboding, foretelling*, vs idiomatic Ger. *dicker Bauch* "big belly", akin to *thick*, but with only Germanic and Celtic derivations at the PIE level. I'm saying *dick* stems from a sense "in-*dic*-ation"; ironically, *big* is rather uncertain and likely pertains to the root *bhew-, that's often glossed "to swell", whence also Ger. *Bauch*, "belly". The wonders of life, ey? Venus figurines of big belly girls are among the oldest pieces of art we know, around 30.000 years old.

I also see "dick" here, comparing "digitus".

I'm not sure how *tewteH-, "strong, powerfull, mighty" figures into this. Maybe compare *to tug*, Ger. *ziehen*, *Zug*, PIE *dewk- "to pull; to lead" (Note the accent on ḱ for *deyḱ- though). For the Anlaut we can compare *(s)teH- "stand, set" on the one hand and *deH- "do, put place" on the other, with various extenstions around *(s)te- (for *stiff*, etc. etc.). Arguably, a prefix *(s)- could fortify a coda *deH- to *(s)t- > *t-. I'm betting on the prefix reflecting "ex".

Further compare *dyke*, "ditch", *dʰeygʷ- ‘to stick, set up’; The difference should be as small as between Ger. "Zeugs", "Zeug" and "zeugen"; (saying so because for *dyke* we observe "Lithuanian *diegti* ‘to prick; plant’, dýgsti ‘to geminate, grow’"; cp. Ger. *Erzeugnis*, "produce"; Further, cogante German *Teich* "pond", Latin *fīgō* "to affix" imply that Ger. *angelegt* relates, which pertains to seed beds as well as to ponds, further to clothes and eventually to ships tied in harbor"). Thus, "ditch" does remind of the above mentioned "leave" as well as of Lat. "lego", or rather Ger. "legen".

And then some ...

All that's to say, it--*das Deuten*--is yet uncertain.

Comment: Why was vectory's answer downvoted?

Comment: Because it is a long rambling mess that mostly doesn't answer the question and where it tried to, it's wrong. The root *deyk is not going to become deut- in German.

Comment: @siride A long rambling mess? Whereas the development of PIE to Germanic was a short, clean (enirely regular, ha ha, not!) process? To the other point, you have to read "\*deyḱ" as a symbol with meaning derived from its context. The given context is not focused on sound laws, so WTH are you talking about? If strict adherence to established sound laws inhibits your reading ability, I cannot help it. PIE \*h₂éḱmō is also not going to become PBS \*akmō and yet, [here it is](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/35209/any-reasons-for-unexplained-centumization-in-balto-slavic)! smh